# Fill a textbox with jQuery

Tags: jquery

When I use this code, it doesn't want to work.

```
$('[id$=ADRESTextBox]').text(data[0]);
```

The data is an array as you can see.  It really has a value (because I alerted it)
How do you fill a certain textbox with jQuery.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set values of form elements with [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
$('[id$=ADRESTextBox]').val(data[0]);
```

If you are talking about text [`input` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/input): They don't have "content" anyway. It is a single, self-closing tag, so any attempt to put something *inside* the tag will fail. A text field's value is defined by its `value` attribute.

**Update:**

With respect to the comment: If `ADRESTextBox` is actually the full ID, use `$('#ADRESTextBox')` to select the element.

Comment: Also using the pound selector for IDs '#ADRESTextBox' is a bit more standard.

Comment: @Spencer Ruport: If the full ID is `ADRESTextBox`, then yes of course. But the code uses the *ends with* selector, so it might be that several input boxes are selected.

Comment: A note, the poster may be using the selector syntax [name$=] to select multiple textareas at once, so the changes are made together. So they are not synonymous, although that could be what the poster needs (can't tell without more info).

Comment: Oh my mistake! I didn't realize that was an ends-with selector.